# RequiredFieldValidator not working programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

As the title says. What could be amiss?

I have a regular TextBox on my page - `<asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server"  />`

The following works:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="r" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tb" ErrorMessage="error" />
```

The following does not work:

```
RequiredFieldValidator rfv = new RequiredFieldValidator();
rfv.ID = "rfv";
rfv.ControlToValidate = tb.ID;
rfv.ErrorMessage = "error";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add your required field validator

```
RequiredFieldValidator rfv = new RequiredFieldValidator();
rfv.ID = "rfv";
rfv.ControlToValidate = tb.ID;
rfv.ErrorMessage = "error";
yourFormId.Controls.Add(rfv);// you need to add this
```